# How to integrate a WPF Application into Unity3D project?

Tags: wpf, xaml, unity-game-engine

It's possible to integrate my WPF application into Unity3D ?

PS = Unity will be used only to Display my 2D application.

Comment: yes, it seems to resolve my question

Comment: just a note, you can close your own question as duplicate.